# Why is the Steppers Component of Material Design now 'archived'?

Tags: material-design

I noticed that the Steppers Component are now under 'Archived' instead of with the 'Active' guidelines. See https://material.io/archive/guidelines/components/steppers.html
 (July 2019).

Does anybody know why they are phased out? Poor usability? Or are there rumours that they will they be replaced with a similar component?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The Stepper Component is not literally archived, **the website your are looking is**.

Google introduced a new version of material.io website in [May 2018](https://material.io/whats-new/#announcements) with less components description but kept online former versions of the specifications as you can see here : https://material.io/archive/guidelines/

You can find more about this May 2018 update in the Google Design 
Blog Post "[Making More with Material](https://design.google/library/making-more-with-material/)"

All current specified components of the new update are now linked to a technical implementation. The stepper component was indeed specified but never technically implemented as part of the MD web components, take a look at this [GitHub Issue](http://specifications) from October.

Keep in mind that Google Material Design specifications and components are constantly evolving, while it seems MD started as broad guidelines, I have now the feeling that the project is really becoming a component library.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot for the link to the article. It mostly speaks about theming though, not about phasing out components :)

Comment: Hence, I'm still confused as to why it is archived. The material.io Stepper guideline page now even throws a 404, while in reality we still need a wizard-like component in our UX work. https://material.io/archive/guidelines/components/steppers.html

Comment: Also, Frameworks like Angular still support the Stepper: https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview

Comment: [QUOTE](...) while it seems MD started as broad guidelines, I have now the feeling that the project is really becoming a component library[/QUOTE] True, but I think this is desirable given the widespread audience. A better approach for them would have been to keep guidelines on UX and Code together, to prevent the two from living their own live (and hence deviating too much). See 'Architecting the Component Page' in this article as to why: https://medium.com/eightshapes-llc/documenting-components-9fe59b80c015

Comment: Finally: sorry for the bunch of comments. Apparently, I can't add line breaks / text formatting in here :)

Comment: The GitHub issue link is not a link to anywhere. Not sure what it was originally supposed to point to